# How to install tflearn, Anaconda Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using Anaconda on ubuntu 16.04.
I try pip install tflearn on terminal and says ok.
But if I try to check the tflearn version, I receive this log.
I appreciate any hint to solve this issue.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/libardo/Datos/Proyectos/Libardo/2017/Proyectos/Kaggle/MBA/prueba_TF_Version.py", line 12, in <module>
    import tflearn as tfl; print(tfl.__version__)
  File "/home/libardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import config
  File "/home/libardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/config.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .variables import variable
  File "/home/libardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/variables.py", line 7, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops import add_arg_scope as contrib_add_arg_scope
  File "/home/libardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib import factorization
  File "/home/libardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/factorization/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.factorization.python.ops.gmm import *
  File "/home/libardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/factorization/python/ops/gmm.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators import estimator
  File "/home/libardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/__init__.py", line 87, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import *
  File "/home/libardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import *
  File "/home/libardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import estimators
  File "/home/libardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/__init__.py", line 297, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators.dnn import DNNClassifier
  File "/home/libardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn.py", line 29, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators import dnn_linear_combined
  File "/home/libardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn_linear_combined.py", line 31, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators import estimator
  File "/home/libardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.learn_io import data_feeder
  File "/home/libardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/learn_io/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.learn_io.dask_io import extract_dask_data
  File "/home/libardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/learn_io/dask_io.py", line 26, in <module>
    import dask.dataframe as dd
  File "/home/libardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/dataframe/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .core import (DataFrame, Series, Index, _Frame, map_partitions,
  File "/home/libardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py", line 38, in <module>
    pd.computation.expressions.set_use_numexpr(False)
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'computation'
```

Comment: which pandas version? ....import pandas; print pandas.__version__

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the pandas version is old. Try follow the following steps:

> https://www.scipy.org/install.html

Another reason for your problem can be due your version of Python, like too the version of your pip. Please, verify if your pip have that libraries with:

> pip list
>
> pip2 list
>
> pip3 list

The use of this commands depends your Python and pip version.